# Matlab: how to plot a stacked 3D bar plot in (x,y,z)-coordinates?

Tags: matlab, 3d, stack

I'd like to plot a stacked 3D bar in three-dimensional coordinates, i.e., given x, and y, z is a stacked 3D bar. It seems like Matlab only supports such plot in two-dimensional coordinates.

for example, how to plot such a stacked 3D bar in (x,y,z) space using the following data sets?

```
    x, y, z
    1, 2, (3+4)
    1, 1, (5+6)
    2, 1, (1+1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You already had a look at the [`bar3` examples](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html)? Or what else do you want, what is not covered by the examples there?

Comment: Yes I have. The example of "3-D Bar Graph with Stacked Style" there is clearly two dimensional in terms of coordinations. As I described in my question, I'd like to specify some points on the (x, y) plain, and then plot stacked bars at that specified points. In other words, given x, and y, plot z which is a stacked bar.

Answer (score 0):

You have two general approaches you can take...

1. **Plot your own bars (i.e. cuboids):** You can create a function that takes the sets of values and plots the cuboid surfaces at those points. There are a few ways to create basic 3D cubes, which are covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002476/how-can-i-draw-multiple-3d-cubes-in-matlab) and [this MATLAB Newsgroup thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/235581). You would just have to scale, shift, and recolor the cube surfaces accordingly. If this seems a daunting task, then...
2. **Make multiple [BAR3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html) plots, modifying each accordingly:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13156133/52738) covers how to make a grid of stacked bar plots. In your case, you probably wouldn't want a full grid, but sparse stacked bars scattered at different coordinates in a region. In this case, you could format your data to work with the solution in the above question by creating 2-D sets of data for `z`, filled with zeroes where you don't want any bars. Then you can remove the unwanted zero-value bars at each step using the solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2050367/52738).